# Tableau Prep Calculated field to subtract Q3 YTD from Q4 YTD to get Q4 QTD

Tags: tableau-api

I have dataset that has only YTD data (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 YTD). 
I want to add calculated field that calculates QTD data based on YTD values.

Data is given in this manner:

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zDh7.png)

I want to get QTD values in calculated field (new column) from this that is more like this:

[YTD and QTD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzvKi.png)

Point is that I have to get QTD value (example Q4) based on difference between one YTD value (example Q4) and previous YTD value (example Q3) for the same line, same year, same name.

In excel you could do this using SUMIFS to sum by using specific criteria and make a difference from previous YTD value for the same line. I dont have this function in Tableau Prep so I need you help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date field and  the "Value" field is a measure, Tableau
should calculate YTD and QTD for you.

Place the date field on the left side (rows) and chose to show year, and then do it again and chose to show
quarter, then place your measure on the sheet. To have it as a running total, use a calculated field
with a formula like this:

```
sum([VALUE])+ PREVIOUS_VALUE(0)
```

It should look something like this:

[YTD QTD Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1TKB.png)